How to show that $0 \leq \mathrm{tr}[\rho P] \leq 1$ for a density matrix $\rho$ and a projection $P$?
Let $\rho$ be a density matrix for hilbert space of dimension $n$ (satisfying $\rho^\dagger = \rho$ and $\mathrm{tr}[\rho] =1$ and $\rho \geq 0$).
Let $P$ be a projection operator. This means $P^2 = P$.
How do we prove that $0 \leq \mathrm{Tr}[\rho P] \leq 1$?
My attempt: write $P = | \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi |$ as well as $\rho = \sum_i p_i | i \rangle \langle i |$ where $\sum_i p_i = 1$ and $0\leq p_i \leq 1$. Then:
$$
\mathrm{tr}[\rho P] = \sum_i p_j | \langle \Psi | i \rangle |^2
$$
Each $| \langle \Psi | i \rangle |^2$ is a probability and so lies between 0 and 1. I don't see how this quantity is bounded by 1.
EDIT: Can one generalize this bound to something similar involving two density matrices $\mathrm{tr}[\rho \rho']$?

This sounds like a homework question…


Probably you mean orthogonal projection operator satisfying $P^2=P$ and $P^\dagger=P$. 2. $P=|\Psi\rangle \langle \Psi|$ with $\langle \Psi |\Psi\rangle=1$ is not the general form of such an orthogonal projector. 3. Cauchy-Schwarz might be helpful.


I second the comment by @Hyperon -- anyway, you are basically there with your method already: just bound each probability by $1$ (as you already said) and make use that the sum of the $p_i$ is also $1$... For the generalization, simply note that $\mathrm{Tr} \rho P = \langle \psi, \rho \psi\rangle$ with your choice of $P$ (normalized $\psi$), and you've showed that  $\langle \psi, \rho \psi\rangle\leq 1$ -- simply expand the trace $\mathrm{Tr}\rho\rho^\prime$ in a suitable (orthonormal) basis and in a one-liner you're there, too.

It sounds a homework question, so instead of doing it for you, I'll give you some tips that maybe will be helpful.

Don't forget that all $p_i$ are positive. It means that the expression you get is a statistical mixture of positive values. What properties a statistical mixture could have? Try to play it with small dimension, like with only $p_1$ and $p_2$ first, gather some intuition and go for the general case.

When you have a sum of bounded quantities, this sum is bounded, can you figure how?

When searching for bounds, sometimes it is useful to start with s inequality that you already know it's true. For example, you know that $\rho^2$ is positive definite, so
$$
tr{\rho^2} \geq 0
$$
Does it helps?

Last tip, if you apply the reasoning above for a combination like $a\rho+b\sigma$, where $a,b\geq 0$, you will have a inequality, due to the geometry of the space of positive semidefinite matrices (it's a convex cone). Know you can improve it, by minimization under variables $a,b$. Try to find what it gives to you.


